# Create a role in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for the possibility to create a role in a mysql database like

```
CREATE ROLE dev;
```

Is this possible in mysql?

Comment: are you checking for user permissions and privileges in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 introduced [support for roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html)

Previous versions don't have direct support for roles, but [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-adding-roles.html) does have a feature to let you manage users in this way.

Comment: Roles available (finally) in MySQL version 8.